# token based authentication in a distributed servers using database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, soa, token, auth-token

I am developing a application with distributed servers using service oriented architecture, here is [link for my system architecture](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B64IY9K4W3GfSktEY1N4WTNUWG8). 
It is a Rails 3 application, where I have 2 content processing servers and 2 application servers. All the user uploads(images/videos) goes to content processing server and all the web pages are served through application server.
I am using devise gem for authentication purpose and it is token based authentication. 
All the interactions with the servers are done using HTTP based rest API's. 
Every request sends a auth_token to the server, which then server verifies it by checking the auth_token in the database and every thing is working fine, but i am not sure about following things -

1. Since every request is verified using database, will it not over load the database server when their are lot of users say 1 million
2. I considered using sessions to store this auth_token during login and verify the request auth_token on every request, since i am using multiple servers for application and content processing, so i need to go for sticky session or creating session on all the server, which i don't want to do.

Is their any other way I can do token based authentication with out putting load on the database server in a distributed servers environment?